# Why can't I update this MongodDB document in the first callback function (while I'm able to update a different document without issues)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Sorry if the title is confusing, I had a hard time summarizing the problem in a single question. I am currently implementing a comment system for a very generic article posting/reading web app using the MEAN stack.

I currently have models for `Author`, `Article`, and `Comment` which look like the following (omitting irrelevant fields like createdBy):

```
var AuthorSchema = new Schema({
    // removing unnecessary fields  
    articles: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Article'
    }],
    comments: [{     // want to find all of a users comments quickly
        type: Schema.ObjectId,    
        ref: 'Comment'
    }]
    ...
}

var CommentSchema = new Schema({
    // removing unnecessary fields  
    content: {
        type: String
    },
    author: {  // I want to be able to find a comment's author quickly
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Author'
    },
    ...
}

var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    content: {
        type: String
    },
    author: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Author'
    },
    comments: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Comment'
    }]
    ...       
}
```

Here is my code for creating a comment in my Comment controller:

```
commentCtrl.createComment = function(req, res, next) {
var comment = new Comment(req.body);
if (req.user) {
    comment.author = req.user;
    // the desired article is stored on the req object by earlier middleware
    req.article.comments.unshift(comment); // naive way to add comment
    req.article.save(
        function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return sendError(res, 400, getErrorMessage(err));
        } else {
            Author.findByIdAndUpdate(
                req.user._id,
                {$push: {comments: comment}},
                function(err){
                    res.json(comment);
                }
            )
        }
    });

}
else {
    return sendError(res, 401,'The user is not logged in.');
}
};
```

So now the weird part. The author is correctly storing the comment in the comments array field whereas the article is not. After execution, here is a console log of the article which references the author (again, I removed irrelevant fields for clarity):

```
{ _id: 56a7b5028bffef9e1ba58ab4,
  author: 
   { _id: 56a7b1791a5f728c1bb1ee99,
     username: 'xTest1',
     comments: 
      [ 53a78291a5f728c1bbcef9b ],
     articles: 
      [ 53a78291a5f728c1bbcef9a ],
   },
  title: 'Test article',
  content: '...',
  comments: []
}
```

My original thought was that my naive approach of unshifting the comment to the comments array was not working, so while I already had the article object on the req object, I changed the implementation to mimic the code that seems to be working for updating author:

```
Article.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.article._id,
    {$push: {comments: comment}},
    function(err){ ... // same inner function as above (to update author)
    }
}
```

That didn't change anything at all. I'm not getting any error messages (which makes sense since the inner callback is working just fine), so I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, and I feel a bit silly. Hopefully by answering my own question, I can prevent others from the same mistake.

I was not creating a Comment document in the database. I was simply creating a Comment in the application, then storing references to it (or rather, trying to) in the Author and the Article documents.

The solution was to first save the Comment in the db, then carry out original code in the successful callback function.

The one thing I can't figure out is why it was successfully storing a reference in the Author object at all? If anyone has ideas about that it might shed light on some dormant problem that I can't foresee.